# Spark JDBC: Incorrect syntax in spark.read

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read maximum `id` value in my table by using

```py
  _select_sql = f"(SELECT MAX(id) FROM {tablename})"
  highest_id = spark.read.jdbc(url, table=_select_sql, properties=properties)
```

After executing this I am getting :

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword &#39;WHERE&#39;`

When I try to read all data using `highest_id = spark.read.jdbc(url, table=tablename, properties=properties)` evrything is fine.

Do you know where could be mistake?

Edit:

After changing to

```py
_select_sql = f"(SELECT MAX(id) FROM {tablename}"
```

I am getting:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '0'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using

```py
_select_sql = f"(SELECT TOP(1) id FROM {tablename} ORDER BY id DESC)"
```

Thanks anyway to [Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott), It works only in way that he gave. Don t really know why because of some sources tells this should work in similar way:

```py
df = spark.read.jdbc(url = url, table = query, properties = properties)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using query as a table name - this will not work. You need to use the `query` option instead (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)):

```py
highest_id = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
  .option("query", f"SELECT MAX(id) FROM {tablename}") \
  .load()
```

Comment: According to this [link](https://medium.com/@usmanazhar4/how-to-read-and-write-from-database-in-spark-using-pyspark-150d39cdbb72) that should works and after changing I am still getting `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'`

Answer (score 1):

Spark internally creates a SQL statement like

```sql
SELECT * FROM <table>
```

So, if you want a statement as table parameter it has to look like this (just adding a name to the inline view):

```py
_select_sql = f"(SELECT MAX(id) FROM {tablename}) tab"
```

and sparks cretated SQL will look like this and do the job:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable) tab
```